# Why can I not install NHibernate framework into my ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate

My project has a 5-layer architecture. I am trying to have Entity Framework and NHibernate in the core of my project.

The project .net framework version is at 4.6. I am getting the following message.
Requesting immediate help. Thanks for sharing your ideas

> Install-Package : Could not install package 'NHibernate 5.1.3'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package nhibernate
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
>
> Time Elapsed: 00:00:00.3142509

Updated: Solved by selecting the version according to ASP.net MVC 5

Answer (score 2):

You’ll need to use .net framework 4.6.1 instead of 4.6.

See https://www.nuget.org/packages/NHibernate/5.1.3 under dependencies.

Comment: I cant not update my .netFramework version even i need to make it 4.5 according to company standard

Comment: I solved the question by Finding the last year version of NHibernate